# For o365 is there any client side API available for File.ReleaseLock(File.LockId)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, office365api, sharepointdocumentlibrary, o365rwsclient

In SharePoint there is server side API available using SSOM and Power shell script   , but can we do same using CSOM , JSOM OR REST API ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is not a client API to achieve it currently for SharePoint Online.

Check the official document below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file_members.aspx